# How do I change " with '

Tags: javascript, sql-server, string

I'm trying to run query from JS which execute in sql server.
This query should find a user in db according it's username and password:

```
var str = "SELECT * FROM Users where (username = " + params.user + ") and (password = " + params.password + ")";
```

Which params are parameters sends by the user in url:

```
localhost:8888/login?user="abc"&password="123"
```

But the value of str is:

```
str = SELECT * FROM Users where (username = "abc") and (password = "123")
```

I tried to use string.replace to replace the " with ' but when I print str it written with " instead of '.

Any suggestions? Probably I'm not the first one have this problem...

Comment: This is an invitation for sql-injection, isn't it?

Comment: Also no password hashing! I really hope this is not on a production server...

Comment: I think this is an exercise guys...

Comment: No it doesn't, just my application...

Comment: In this case we all reccommend you to read something about sql-injection, and in general about web security.

Comment: I'll do it, thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

insert the ' in your SELECT, like this:

```
var str = "SELECT * FROM Users where (username = '" + params.user + "') and (password = '" + params.password + "')";
```

And remove the " from request:

```
localhost:8888/login?user=abc&password=123
```

Comment: The query should be parameterized.  Never build a SQL statement string by concatenating user input.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP: Didn't I use parameters? Is there any pattern to do it? Should I encrypt it on client side and decrypt it on server side?

Comment: @user2004403, I added an answer with the parameters SQL code.  The key is to use parameter names in the SQL statement, and add the parameter objects to the command with the desired values separately.  This is a best practice and mitigates the risk of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var str = "SELECT * FROM Users where (username = " + params.user.replace(/"/g, "'") + ") and (password = " + params.password.replace(/"/g, "'") + ")";
```

It'll replace the double quotes with the single ones..

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/3k8mz0v2/2/)**

Comment: The query should be parameterized. Never build a SQL statement string by concatenating user input even if an attempt is made to sanitized the value.  Consider if the result of the value is "NULL;DROP TABLE Users;--"

Answer (score 0):

Below is a parameterized SQL example to accomplish this task.

```
var str = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Users where (username = @username) and (password = @password)";

var command = new SqlCommand(str, connection);

var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>()
{
    new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Size = 30, Value = params.user },
    new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar) { size = 30, Value = params.password },
};    

command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
```